# How to give default html text inside a div?

Tags: html, contenteditable

I am using a content-editable div

`<div id='contenteditable' ... >`
`<html>`
`<body>`
`AS plain text`
`</body>`
`</html>`
`</div>`

When the page load i want this html content inside the div as a simple text in it.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be hard with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contenteditable').val($('#contenteditable').html());
});
```